# If 2 jqgrid tables are present(with frozen functionality) in same page, frozen columns are not working properly

Tags: jqgrid

If 2 jqgrid tables are present(with frozen functionality) in same page, frozen columns are not working properly.

Second table works fine. But the first table header is messed up. Seems there is some bug in jqgrid css.

Oleg please help :)

Comment: @Oleg: Expecting your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adjusting the some CSS properties.